# Is there any solvent I can mix with DMSO to lower its boiling point?

Tags: boiling-point

Is there a way, or a solvent I can mix with DMSO to lower its boiling point?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Cosolvent

Any miscible solvent with a lower boiling point than DMSO, especially ones that show positive deviation from Raoult's law, will lower the boiling point of the solution. According to Reference 1, the following may be utilized:

1. Alkyl-benzenes from benzene (unsubstituted) to tert-butyl benzene.
2. Haloalkanes such as tetrachloromethane, 1-chlrohexane/pentane/butane,
   and 1,1,2,2-tetrachloroethane.

If you are trying to do a reaction, haloalkanes maybe somewhat reactive.

Do try to achieve an azeotropic solution so the concentration and boiling point does not vary while you are evaporating the solvent.

#### Lowering the Pressure

By definition, boiling point is the temperature at which vapor pressure of liquid becomes equal to the external (atmospheric) pressure. Thus, if you reduce the external pressure, it will reduce the boiling point of DMSO.

#### Reference

1. Marongiu, B., Piras, A., Porcedda, S., Tuveri, E. (2007). A comparitive study of Thermodynamic Properties of Binary Mixtures Containing Dimethylsulfoxide. *Journal of Thermal Analysis and Calorimetry*, *90*, 909–922. [10.1007/s10973-007-7885-2](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10973-007-7885-2).